# Mocking Jersey Client

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am trying to mock the Jeresy webservice call. I have stubbed the WebService.Resource get() method. I am getting the ClientHandlerException. Looks like its calling the real method instead of the stub. Am I missing something in the way the method is stubbed?

when(webResourceBuilderMock.get(ClientResponse.class)).thenReturn(clientResponseMock );

Exception:
Embedded exception: Wrapped Exception Class -> class com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter.handle(LoggingFilter.java:217)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509)
at xxx.xx.xx.xx.xxx.xxxx.WebServiceClientImpl1.getCreditCardDetails(WebServiceClientImpl1.java:173)
at xxx.xx.xx.xx.xxx.xxxx.WebServiceClientTest.testAWebServiceClient(WebServiceClientTest.java:121)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.jav

WebServiceClientImpl.java

```
            String wsURL = appendResorcePath("/xx/xx/xx/" + id + "/xxx");
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
            clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
            Client restClient = Client.create(clientConfig);
            WebResource webResource = restClient.resource(wsURL);
            restClient.addFilter(new com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter(printStream));
            WebResource.Builder webResourceBuilder = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            webResourceBuilder = webResourceBuilder.header(Constants.AUTHORIZATION, Constants.BASIC + createAuthString()).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
            clientResp = webResourceBuilder.get(ClientResponse.class);
```

Test Class Code:

```
    WebResource webResourceMock = Mockito.mock(WebResource.class);
    WebResource.Builder webResourceBuilderMock = Mockito.mock(WebResource.Builder.class);
    ClientResponse clientResponseMock = Mockito.mock(ClientResponse.class);
    clientResponseMock.setStatus(200);
    ObjectMapper objectMapperMock = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
    
    when(webResourceMock.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).thenReturn(webResourceBuilderMock);
    when(webResourceBuilderMock.header(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn(webResourceBuilderMock);
    when(webResourceBuilderMock.get(ClientResponse.class)).thenReturn(clientResponseMock );
```